# Why does the lights disapear when ever I make lights near each other unity (spotlight)

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I have been making a game in unity and I cant put street lamps because if I put 10 or so near each other  half of them stop making light, How can I fix this.
Thanks!
(project made in URP)

Comment: Number of lights allowed per pixel is a setting, from memory it's either in preferences > quality settings or in the lighting settings. BTW 10 lights near each other is a lot and will affect performance significantly. It's best to try to do more with less - play around with the light settings try try to achieve the same effect with less lights. Consider also area lighting, baked lighting and emissive materials.

Comment: i cant make light lamps for roads :(

Comment: it wont let me cuz they disappear

Comment: @Absinthe there is no quality or lighting in performanc

Comment: OH i opened preferences

Comment: anyway is it possible to change the thing and make light visable?

Comment: it sudently changed the thing now i cant add more than:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wxeBA6mSI3Rdb1pHGwJF6gzf-7-wEnKn/view?usp=sharing the img no need to download wait for load

Comment: Rather than spam comments please update your post to show what you've tried. Also, no one is going to click a random Google Drive link :) Either use an image link or explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality -> Pixel Light Count and you'll see the number 4 by default. Write there the number of light that you want to see.

[image]